# "О что он ударился?" или "Обо что он ударился?"

Tags: предлоги

Почему в русском появился предлог "обо", если был предлог "о"?

Answer (score 1):

Это связано с сочетаниями согласных.

Словарь Ушакова:
Употребляется в сочетаниях: *обо мне, **обо что**, обо всё*, а также наряду с "о" в сочетаниях: *обо всём, обо всей, обо всех*; в разговорной речи встречаются редкие случаи употребления "обо" перед некоторыми группами согласных, напр. *обо льне*.